# Issue On Inserting Auto Incremented ID in MySQL Using Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have table in MySQL database called `MyGuests`  which has 4 fields as : id (PK and Auto Increment), name,age and email. I am using following code to insert data from user input form to the database:

```
<?php
$sql = mysqli('localhost','user','password','database');
$name  = $_POST['name'];
$age   = $_POST['age'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$query = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests ( id, name, age, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

$query->bind_param("isis",$name,$age,$email);

$query->execute();
?>
```

now I am confused how to insert value for `id` which is auto incremented field using the Prepared statement! As you can see I passed 4 parameters as `(?, ?, ?, ?)` for data entry and used the  `"isis"` for bind_param(); but not sure what must put in `$name,$age,$email` for id?

Can you please help me to figure this out?

Thanks

Comment: Just leave it empty or take it away from the query. It's auto incrementing, you don't have to do anything :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just omit the `id` in the query i.e.

```
INSERT INTO MyGuests ( name, age, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

It will automatically add the incremented id, hence the name :)

Comment: Thanks anthonygore, can you please let me know what should we do about field with default value specified? like if I have a field called invited and has a default value as 0, (this must be updated to 1 after receiving confirmation ) how can I insert it to table among other inputs?

Comment: If you want to write a value to that field, specify it in your query. If you just want the default value, omit it, just like `id` in the above.

Comment: I think you can also put `DEFAULT` as the value of any field where you want the default value (for example, if you wanted a visual queue that you were writing default values to particular fields), but omitting them from the query altogether does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

one more option is supplying null value to the auto-increment column:

ie.
instead of 
`$query = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests ( id, name, age, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");` 
use 
`$query = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests ( id, name, age, email) VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?)");`